# Optional Regex for URL Rewriting: How to make a part of URL fully optional?

Tags: regex, apache2

a short question about **optional regex**:

imagine a given page thats currently rewritten/beautified to:

`/xx/somepage/description-description-description`

while actually loading the ugly url below water:

`/somepage?ln=xx`

via this seemingly working rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/(.*)/(.*?)$ /$2?ln=$1 [L]
```

However, currently the last portion `/description` is now compulsory. Without it error 404 occurs. What RewriteRule should I use to make the third and last part optional? Especially since it has no file-fetching meanings and is only for the user to make a url more descriptive.

In other words, I would like all three of the below to work the same way:

```
/xx/somepage
/xx/somepage/description-description-description
```

thanks very much

## update

both of these seem to work fine:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/(.*?)(/.*)?$   /$2?ln=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ /$2?ln=$1 [L]
```

the difference being on the the middle part. I gather it has something to do with greedyness... but why/how they differ exactly... someone else might be able to shed light here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the final `/` in your rule, or place it in an optional group. As it stands, and from what I see, the description isn't *completely* necessary,  but a trailing slash is.

New RegEx:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/(.*?)(/.*)?$ /$2?ln=$1 [L]
```

Comment: +1 i think thats it, but, how do I place that slash in an optional group sothat IF description is added, it should go behind a / indeed, if I understand your suggestion.. and I think I do...

Comment: @Sam: Add a question mark after it. That will tell refectory it should occur 0-1 times.

Comment: like so?  `RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/(.*)/?(.*?)$ /$2?ln=$1 [L]`   problem is that now the without discription works, but with /description does not work?!

Comment: @Sam: That, or use `(/.+)?`. You may or may not have to change the `/(.*)/` to `/(.*?)/`, too (the `?` after the `*` makes it un-greedy.

Comment: None of them works!?!? either the /xx/page  or the /xx/page/description work but never both.. :(  log says `mod_rewrite: maximum number of internal redirects reached. Assuming configuration error. Use 'RewriteOptions MaxRedirects' to increase the limit if neccessary.
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace. `

Comment: @Sam: See my updated answer. I tried it on my end and it works (see if the same holds true for you)

Comment: how do I setup the log level debug to get backtrace? I have plesk. Should I write a specific line below the RewriteRule so it backtraces/logs the error? Thanks very much

Comment: Incredible, now it works! Cannot find out why but oh well.. must have been me. I am sure the gigital gods of 06:00 AM +1 GMT have blessed the night with their fruitfullness. Much appreciated Brad! awesome.

Comment: @Sam: hackathon? Happens to the best of us. ;-) Happy coding, and try to sleep during the commenting portion of your code, not the meat-n-potatoes part. ;p

Comment: Hope this helps you: ^([a-z][a-z])/([a-z]+)/?([a-z]*/?)$
This will work for xx/someone, xx/someone/, xx/someone/description, xx/someone/description/

Answer (score 1):

You may need to ensure that the second pattern doesn't include a slash:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ /$2?ln=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Making the middle catch ungreedy also satisfies this.

Comment: @Brad Christie: Yes, if you use `(.*?)(/.*)?` (as your latest update shows), but not if you use `(.*?)(/.+)?`. The latter will run into problems for patterns with trailing slashes like `/xx/somepage/`.